# Flutter Loader Animation not centered if in Column

Tags: flutter, animation, dart

I've followed a tutorial on youtube, explaining how to create a wonderful loader.
Everything works fine, but if I put the Loader inside a Column, the center is shifted, and I really can't understand why. Could you please help me? I'm not very able in handling Flutter animations, but I like this very much and I really want to understand what mistake I am making. Thank you!

Loader code:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Loader extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoaderState createState() => _LoaderState();
}

class _LoaderState extends State<Loader> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation<double> animationRotation;
  Animation<double> animationRadiusIn;
  Animation<double> animationRadiusOut;

  final double initialRadius = 70;
  double radius = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
    );

    animationRotation = Tween<double>(
      begin: 0.0,
      end: 1.0,
    ).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: controller,
        curve: Interval(
          0.0,
          1.0,
          curve: Curves.linear,
        ),
      ),
    );

    animationRadiusIn = Tween<double>(
      begin: 1.0,
      end: 0.0,
    ).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: controller,
        curve: Interval(
          0.75,
          1.0,
          curve: Curves.elasticIn,
        ),
      ),
    );
    animationRadiusOut = Tween<double>(
      begin: 0.0,
      end: 1.0,
    ).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: controller,
        curve: Interval(
          0.0,
          0.25,
          curve: Curves.elasticOut,
        ),
      ),
    );

    controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        if (controller.value >= 0.75 && controller.value <= 1.0) {
          radius = animationRadiusIn.value * initialRadius;
        } else if (controller.value >= 0.0 && controller.value <= 0.25) {
          radius = animationRadiusOut.value * initialRadius;
        }
      });
    });

    controller.repeat();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RotationTransition(
      turns: animationRotation,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Dot(
            radius: 90,
            color: Colors.black12,
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(radius * cos(pi / 4), radius * sin(pi / 4)),
            child: Dot(
              radius: 10,
              color: Colors.redAccent,
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(
                radius * cos(2 * pi / 4), radius * sin(2 * pi / 4)),
            child: Dot(
              radius: 10,
              color: Colors.greenAccent,
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(
                radius * cos(3 * pi / 4), radius * sin(3 * pi / 4)),
            child: Dot(
              radius: 10,
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(
                radius * cos(4 * pi / 4), radius * sin(4 * pi / 4)),
            child: Dot(
              radius: 10,
              color: Colors.purple,
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(
                radius * cos(5 * pi / 4), radius * sin(5 * pi / 4)),
            child: Dot(
              radius: 10,
              color: Colors.amberAccent,
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(
                radius * cos(6 * pi / 4), radius * sin(6 * pi / 4)),
            child: Dot(
              radius: 10,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(
                radius * cos(7 * pi / 4), radius * sin(7 * pi / 4)),
            child: Dot(
              radius: 10,
              color: Colors.orangeAccent,
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(
                radius * cos(8 * pi / 4), radius * sin(8 * pi / 4)),
            child: Dot(
              radius: 10,
              color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Dot extends StatelessWidget {
  final double radius;
  final Color color;

  Dot({
    this.radius,
    this.color,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        width: radius,
        height: radius,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color, shape: BoxShape.circle),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Non-Working example:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Loader(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Working example:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
        child: Loader(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjcN1.jpg)
[Non-Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nPsO.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found the solution! It was the Stack's alignment. I added

```
alignment: Alignment.center
```

in the Stack and everything worked

Answer (score 0):

Just add Expanded widget over Loader Widget it will work for you.

```
Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(child: Loader()), 
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: @AleTheFe: Edited the answer please have a look

Comment: I'll give it a try, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_loader) to easily add a loader widget to your app

Use it like this:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  //// Wrap your body in a stack
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Center(
        child: Text("Lorem Ipsum"),
      ),
      //// Put the loader widget at the end of the stack. You can set it to appear based on a boolean. E.g. a loading flag.
      EasyLoader(image: AssetImage('assets/loading.png'),)
    ],
  ),
);
```

}